# Does using a PNG to make gradients perform better than having CSS draw them for you?

Tags: html, css, png

I was wondering if there is any significant difference in performance using either of the three.

1.) For PNG, I was thinking either have 2 layers of PNG on top of each other. One with the original image, and then another PNG over it with gradients that match the background layer surrounding the image.

2.) Just have the original PNG image edited by itself the way I want it to look like.

3.) Have the original PNG image with applied gradient tools from CSS.

Performance aside, 1 and 3 would be good for modular components where you need to swap out the original image.

However, I want to know from a pure performance standpoint which method would perform better where if you had a lot of these. Maybe there's another option I don't know about?

Comment: What performances? Network times? Then CSS wins. Computation? Then 2) wins, followed by 4): compute once on a canvas. But really, are you having a performance issue that you think comes from here? Then do benchmarks. Otherwise, just go with the one that makes your life as a web-author the simpler.

Comment: If the goal is achievable by css only, no doubt it's always better than using an image

Comment: @AbhishekPandey wut? You can very well use 9,000,000 1px x 1px <div> + background color to make an image, but that's obviously not gonna be better than using a single 3000 x 3000px JPEG image.

Comment: hmm when I say performance I mean the time it takes to draw everything. Maybe I will do a bench mark test after all later. Knowing network times would also be nice to know too though